# How to create a button in Gmail on click should Tag the selected inbox mails with v-project/deleted label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, gmail

I want to create a button in Gmail under Compose Button (or) in Gmail toolbar.
The expected functionality should support the following scenario like

1. when we select some mails from inbox and click on the button
2. The selected mails should get tagged with "v-project/deleted" label immediately.

Anyone helping with relevant solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question is invalid for stackoverflow. However there's something I can suggest: maybe [gmail.js](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/) library will be useful to you.

Comment: Yes thanks for the suggestion. Actually I am using gmail.js library only as API but not getting how to integrate that functionality with Button and so to achieve the relevant solution.

Comment: Then either try to ask on that lib site or somehow edit the question to make it less broad and more specific (code, etc).

Comment: What about [Gmail Contextual Gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets)?